# run RTOS on 1 core and Linux on other SMP cores?

Tags: linux, arm, kernel, rtos, ethercat

Say we have a 64bit ARM dual core CPU (sysmetric dual cores)

I would like to run a bare RTOS on one core and assign other cores to Linux. in this way I have run a BLDC motor control (using on chip PWM output and ADC input)

So far I would make it happen:

- During the u-boot and kernel, dedicate one core for RTOS, others for Linux
- And reserve a partition of memory as a Linux user-space device, with cache disabled.
- Linux and RTOS exchange info via shared memory
- RTOS controls PWM & GPIO, read ADC, and possibly run a Ethercat connection.

My questions are:

- Do I need to limit memory IO to only one core?
- Have anyone done anything similar? Can anyone point some directions? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean limiting memory-mapped IO access to one core, or limiting DRAM memory access to the same memory area to one core ? I assumed the first option.

Comment: you cant share resources, even if you divide some up there is no doubt you will run into others.  you would need to create linux drivers that communicate with the rtos that owns the shared resources.

Comment: Siemens has done something similar with the [jailhouse](https://github.com/siemens/jailhouse)  project. It does for example allow you to run FreeRTOS on one core, and Linux on the other.

Comment: @Frant Thanks, I will have a look, make sure if the interrupt can be handled in real time manner

Comment: @c2h2: This is a quite different topic. There are reasons why FreeRTOS is more widely used on Cortex-R and Cortex-M profiles.

Comment: yer but nowadays Ethercat requires another equivlant powerful chip to handle, many customers want do 2 job on 1 cpu @Frant

Comment: Could you please provide some details about how to "dedicate one core for RTOS, others for Linux"?  Specifically, how did you boot Linux kernel on core other than core0?